# Do you know why is appearing "Undefined index: questions"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `storeQuantities()` method that stores the quantities of tickets selected by the user in a conference details page.

In this method "`dd($selectedRtypes)`" shows the content below. The questions is empty because there are no questions associated with this conference.

```
array:1 [▼
  "geral" => array:5 [▼
    "quantity" => "2"
    "price" => 0
    "total" => 0
    "questions" => Collection {#255 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    "id" => 1
  ]
]
```

In the registration.blade.php it appears this error:

```
Undefined index: questions
```

With:

```
@if(is_null($selectedRtypes['questions']))

....
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$selectedRtypes['geral']['questions']`

Comment: Thanks but "geral" is dynamic, is stored like:
                "$selectedRtypes[$ttype->name]['questions'] = $ttype->questions". So it can be geral but can other name.

Comment: Can you try `$selectedRtypes[0]['questions']` then? it should then return the first item in the array, in case 'geral' is renamed

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears "Undefined offset: 0".

Comment: Then give this a try: `collect($selectedRtypes)->first()['questions']`